# Не могу создать Круги на карте... Ошибка Uncaught TypeError: this.callInitHooks is not a function

Tags: javascript, 2gis-api

Полная ошибка:

```
script.full.js:15310 Uncaught TypeError: this.callInitHooks is not a function
at t.e [as Circle] (script.full.js:15310)
at Object.success (base.html:30)
at c (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
at l (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
```

Пытался взять координаты с файла GeoJson, чтобы создать маркеры на остановках с информацией о количестве маршрутов (да, там ещё есть информация об маршрутах) и нарисовать круги вокруг него... В итоге маркеры остановок не показываются абсолютно, ошибок не обнаружил, а вот за круги выдаёт ошибку...

Код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>"2ГИС карта с домами и остановками"</title>
            <script src="https://maps.api.2gis.ru/2.0/loader.js?pkg=full"></script>
            <script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="map" style="width:1920px; height:1080px"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var map;
                var data;
                var coord;
                var marker;
                var rast = 1250; //850 //700
                DG.then(function () {
                    map = DG.map('map', {
                        center: [55.707045, 37.515153],
                        zoom: 14
                    });
                    $.getJSON("Ramenki/geojson/moscow_address_coordinates.geojson", function(data) {
                    DG.geoJson(data).addTo(map).bindPopup('Это жилой дом');
                        });
                    $.getJSON("Ramenki/geojson/Ramenki.geojson", function(data) {DG.geoJson(data).addTo(map).bindPopup('Район Раменки (обновите маршруты пж)');})
                    $.getJSON("Ramenki/geojson/moscow_platforms.geojson", function(data) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++)
                        {
                            marker = new L.LatLng(data.features[i].properties.PlatformX,data.features[i].properties.PlatformY);
                            DG.marker(marker).addTo(map).bindPopup("Это остановка\n Тут останавливаются маршруты " + data.features[i].properties.Autobus + "\n Количество маршрутов: " + data.features[i].properties.RoutesCount)
                            DG.Circle(marker,rast, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);
                        }
                    })     
                });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: В общем, как оказалось я недоглядел документацию и примеры... Оказывается надо было использовать Опцию onEachFeature . С кругами попробую разобраться... Но пока ответы принимаю

Comment: в общем нужно использовать pointstoLayer оказывается...